# prop is returning null

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs

I'm not sure why this prop `this.props.event.Who.Name` at the end of my form component is returning an error when the page loads, considering the prop field `Location` is `null`. I'm importing data from a REST API and some of the record fields are `null`. Is there a way to get around this?

Error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null
>       at Update.render (webpack:///./src/components/Event/Update.js?:349:116)

Console of the props before the error.[image]

```
import React from 'react';

class Update extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('event is being submitted for update.');
    console.log(this.props.event);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.event);
    return (
      <form ref={(input) => this.eventForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createEvent(e)} className="slds-form">
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.assignedName = input} type="text" className="slds-input"  value={this.props.event.Owner.Name}  disabled/>
            <input ref={(input) => this.assignedId = input} type="hidden" className="slds-input"  value={this.props.event.Owner.Id} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Related To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.relatedName = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.What.Name} disabled/>
            <input ref={(input) => this.relatedId = input} type="hidden" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.What.Id} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Subject</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.subject = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.Subject}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Location</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.location = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.Location}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event Start</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.start = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.props.event.StartDateTime }/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event End</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.end = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.props.event.EndDateTime } />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="input4">Contact</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <section className="slds-clearfix">
              <input ref={(input) => this.contactName = input} className="slds-input" style={{maxWidth: '92%'}} disabled value={ this.props.event.Who.Name } />
              <input ref={(input) => this.contactId = input} type="hidden" value={ this.props.event.Who.Id }/>
              <button  type="button" onClick={this.toggleModal} className="slds-button slds-button--icon-border slds-float--right" aria-live="assertive" style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlinkHref={searchIcon}></use>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Update</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Update;
```

Comment: I think your console.log is showing you the error. You are rendering {this.props.event.Who.Name } at <input ref={(input) => this.contactName = input} className="slds-input" style={{maxWidth: '92%'}} disabled value={ this.props.event.Who.Name } /> and Who is null. You can check if there is a value for Who before doing Who.name.

Comment: yeah but location is null and it's not giving me an error.

Comment: Its ok to render null, its not ok to dereference null. You could instead do  this.props.event.Who &&  this.props.event.Who.Name. This way it does nothing when Who is not defined, but will render the Name if it is defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is, your are fetching the data from `api`, so you need to hold the `rendering` until you get the data, because until you didn't get the data, `this.props.event.any_key` will be `undefined`, so you need to put a check `Object.keys(this.props.event) > 0 ?` it will work, Use this:

```
render() {
    Object.keys(this.props.event) > 0?
      return (
      <form ref={(input) => this.eventForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createEvent(e)} className="slds-form">
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.assignedName = input} type="text" className="slds-input"  value={this.props.event.Owner.Name}  disabled/>
            <input ref={(input) => this.assignedId = input} type="hidden" className="slds-input"  value={this.props.event.Owner.Id} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Related To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.relatedName = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.What.Name} disabled/>
            <input ref={(input) => this.relatedId = input} type="hidden" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.What.Id} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Subject</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.subject = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.Subject}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Location</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.location = input} type="text" className="slds-input" value={this.props.event.Location}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event Start</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.start = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.props.event.StartDateTime }/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event End</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input ref={(input) => this.end = input} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} className="slds-input" value={ this.props.event.EndDateTime } />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="input4">Contact</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <section className="slds-clearfix">
              <input ref={(input) => this.contactName = input} className="slds-input" style={{maxWidth: '92%'}} disabled value={ this.props.event.Who.Name } />
              <input ref={(input) => this.contactId = input} type="hidden" value={ this.props.event.Who.Id }/>
              <button  type="button" onClick={this.toggleModal} className="slds-button slds-button--icon-border slds-float--right" aria-live="assertive" style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlinkHref={searchIcon}></use>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Update</button>
      </form>
    :
    return <div>fetching data...</div>
```

**Suggestion**: Since your `props` contains a big amount of data so instead on using `this.props.event` all the time you can store the value of `this.props.event` in a separate variable, it will make the code small and readable also. Like this:

```
render(){
   let event = this.props.event;
```

Now use `event` directly instead of `this.props.event`.

Comment: the field `Who.Name ` is null though, it's not a required field for the record. Some records have a value in `Who.Name`, some do not

Comment: in that case you need to put a separate check on that also, like this: `value={ this.props.event.Who ? this.props.event.Who.Id : '' }`.